# What is the #USAGE for Element of arrow function?

Tags: reactjs

for example

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    name: ''
  }

  handelChange = (e ) => { //    <-- here element of e can any one demonstrate for what it used exactly ?

    this.setState({
      name: e.target.value
    })
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className = "App">
        Form Part 1
        <form>
          <input type = "text" onChange = {this.handelChange}/>
          <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
        {this.state.name}
      </div>
    );    
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: A [DOM event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) handler receives an argument representing the [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) that triggered it. That’s what `e` is.

Comment: [Handling events in react](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's  just  a parameter. `e` usually means `event` and come from something like a domEvent (an action from your mouse, keyboard, etc.) :

```
<button onClick={(e) => console.log(e.target)}>Click me</button>
```

Or a parameter you define, like :

```
const saySomething = (value) => {
 console.log(value);
}

<button onClick={() => saySomething('Hello world')}>Click me</button>
```

Note that is the second example, I used an arrow function in the button to call `saySomething` method, it is because the arrow function automatically bind your method to your component context.

Comment: thnx for answering my question :)

Comment: @سبحبحمدالله you're welcome :) if it is the answer you were looking for, don't hesitate to tag it as valid answer ;)